# JSF Datatables : How to handle columns with subtype specific content

Tags: jsf

I have a scenario where I have a list of objects that  extend a common supertype.
This list of objects is supplied to the h:datatable as it's value.

The last column in the table has inputs that are subtype-specific whereas all the other columns apply to fields found in the common superclass.

What is the most elegant way of rendering the subtype-specific fields ?

At the moment I am doing this:

```
<h:column>
  <c:if test="#{cover.cd eq 2}">
     //Markup specific to this subtype
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="#{cover.cd eq 3}">
     //Markup specific to this subtype
  </c:if>
</h:column>
```

Comment: How would you do this outside the datatable? Do it the same here..

Comment: Hi Kukeltjie, seems like this is the only way then...

Comment: No, see the duplicate...